# vue js router + firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I use `vue js 2.4.2` , `vue router 2.7.0` , and `firebase 4.3.0`. I can't get the route authentication stuff to work. This is my current `route.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

import Firebase from './firebase'

import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue'
import Auth from './components/Auth.vue'


let router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: {
                auth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: Auth
        }
    ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
        if (!Firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            next({
                path: '/login'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
})

export default router
```

But now everytime I go to `/` it redirects me back to `/login`, probably because the `Firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null`, even though I am in fact logged in. How do I fix this?

Comment: You Config Initialize Firebase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` instead of `Firebase.auth().currentUser`; it is the recommended way to get the current user.

Getting the user by `currentUser` may cause a problem similar to what you are seeing. This is from the official doc of firebase.

> Note: currentUser might also be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

Try to set you authentication logic like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.auth)) {
        Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (!user) {
                next({
                    path: '/login'
                })
            } else {
                next()
            }
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```